# Using reinterpret_cast to add const to a template class

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

Would this be a correct use of reinterpret_cast or is there some better approach to solve the problem.

```
Node<T>* front_;

Iterator<const T> GetConstIterator() const {
  return Iterator<const T>(reinterpret_cast<Node<const T>*>(front_));
}

Iterator<T> GetIterator() {
  return Iterator<T>(front_);
}
```

The iterator's constructor is defined as this.

```
template<class T>
class Iterator {
  explicit Iterator(Node<T>* const node) : node_(node) {}
  ...
}
```

Comment: Correct? (Most likely) No. Why not use `Node<T> const` and `Iterator<T> const`?

Comment: If the goal is to add `const`, then `const_cast` is probably the right approach.

Comment: Are you unable to construct an `Iterator<const T>` from `front_`?  This type of "problem" usually doesn't need any cast.  Your template parameter is already specifying that `T` will be made `const`.

Comment: Since Iterator's constructor requires a Node of type T it is expecting a "const T" Node pointer

Comment: Are `Node<const T>` and `Node<T>` related (any conversion possible)? Do you need to return an `Iterator<const T>` or something like a `const_iterator`?

Comment: @PeteBecker Why would `const_cast` be the right approach? Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the point of `const_cast` to *remove* the `const` qualifier? That's not to say it can't add it - perhaps it can; I never thought about trying it that way. I'm just curious why you think that `const_cast` is the right approach.

Comment: @NikBougalis - `const_cast` can add and remove `const`. Nothing else. So if all you're doing is adjusting `const`, it's the cast to use.

Comment: @PeteBecker Huh, you learn something new every day...

Comment: @NikBougalis - fuzzy memory here, but there are cases where `const` can't be added implicitly; seems to me it's cases like `int * *const` -> `const int *const *const` that require a `const_cast`.

Comment: Casting a `Node<T>*` to `Node<const T>*` isn't correct, no matter what type of cast you use. These are two independent data types. They may be identical in size, alignment and content, but they are still different types. The right thing to do is to make sure that the constructor for `Iterator<const T>` can take a `Node<const T>*` _and_ a `Node<T>*` as argument. As Drew Dormann said, this is often the case automatically, but if it isn't, perhaps you could add the template definition for `Iterator`, esp. the constructors, to the question?

Comment: Added the Iterators constructor to the question.  I would like to avoid having the Iterator using multiple template classes, like "template<class T, class U>" just to allow for a const of class T.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make your const version of iterator be constructible from a non-const node. Then I would rewrite the getters to be more STL compliant:

```
Iterator<const T> begin() const { return Iterator<const T>(front_); }
Iterator<T> begin() { return Iterator<T>(front_); }
```

All you need to do is make that first version compile. Casting won't work here since `Node<T>` isn't going to be related to `Node<const T>`.

Comment: Iterator's constructor takes in a Node that is templated to class T.  Is there some way to make a Iterator<const T> constructor accept a Node<T>* ? Other than the reinterpret_cast.
explicit Iterator(Node<T>* const node)

Comment: Just make Iterator's constructor take a Node<U>. Can then do a static assert that either U == T or const U == T.

Comment: Having the Iterator as a "template<class T,class U>" would solve the issue but now everywhere that uses Iterator has to declare Iterator's like this for example "Iterator<int, const int> it = ..." which is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to use reinterpret_cast to cast away const-ness. You need to use const_cast for that. You *could* use `reinterpret_cast` to add const-ness, but a `const_cast` is more correct and more evident to future maintainers.

From §5.2.10 Reinterpret cast, p2:

> The reinterpret_cast operator shall not cast away constness (5.2.11).
>   An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member
>   type can be explicitly converted to its own type; such a cast yields
>   the value of its operand.

Really, the constructor of `Node<const T>` should be able to do this implicitly, and the cast shouldn't even be necessary.

The ambiguity arises from your function:

```
Iterator<T> GetIterator() const {
  return Iterator<T>(front_);
}
```

You shouldn't be returning an iterator that can mutate the container as a const method. This method should not have the const-qualifier.

You should just have:

```
Iterator<const T> GetIterator() const {
  return Iterator<const T>(front_);
}

Iterator<T> GetIterator() {
  return Iterator<T>(front_);
}
```

Comment: The issue is from Iterator's constructor which takes in a Node of type "T", which needs to be "const T" for the ConstIterator. front_ is of type Node<T>* but needs to be used as Node<const T>*. To my understanding const_cast cannot do this.  Reinterpret_cast can do this and in "theory" work correctly because it is adding const-ness without changing the actual pointer type.  Although I'm not sure if this is portable. I've seen other implementations that achieve the same result by having the Iterator be defined by multiple template classes but this propagates everywhere.

Comment: The `Iterator` class should be defined as `Iterator<T>`. If you then pass `T` or `const T` into the template, it should work automatically, assuming your iterators are behaving sanely.  reinterpreting `Node<T>*` to `Node<const T>*` will yield undefined behavior as these are not related types.  The need to do so indicates a fundamental design flaw in your interface.

Comment: "const T" and "T" are exactly the same data type in terms of memory, alignment, and content, but differ only by const-ness. So I'm not sure what undefined behavior would happen here?  Note: I'm not trying to cast away const-ness, I am trying to add const-ness to something that isn't const.

Comment: @DavidYoung, yes, `const T` and `T` will behave the same, in this context, but `Node<const T>` and `Node<T>` are distinct types, and will *not* behave the same.  They are distinct types, even though their template arguments are similar.